# CodeIgniter 4 return error : Argument 2 passed to set_value() must be of the type string, object given

Tags: redirect, setvalue, codeigniter-4

I have a contact page which contain a form to send an email. After email get sent, the system will redirect the user to the same page but receive the error

> Argument 2 passed to set_value() must be of the type string, object given

**Function from controller**

```
public function contact(){
    $email = $this->request->getGet('email') ? $this->request->getGet('email') : '';
    
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // ... email submission process
        redirect()->to(base_url('/contact?email='));
    }

    $this->data['email'] = $email;
    return $this->template('pages/contact.tpl.php', $this->data);
}
```

**Input from view**

```
<input
type="text"
class="form-control"
placeholder="Email address"
name="email"
value="<?= !empty($email) ? set_value('email', $email) : set_value('email'); ?>"
required />
```

Based on my code above, if I enter the url `https://www.domain-url/contact?email=testing.mael%40gmail.com` the email will get displayed at email input form at first view. After the form submit and the website get redirected, the page is showing the error above. I'm quite confuse as the error is reading the passed argument value as object

[image]

Comment: You need to fully read the provided error messages. From what it is saying, it appears that somewhere you have assigned $email as an email class object and its thinking that is what $email is on Line 63 in your template. Is the code you have provided the actual code?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes this is an actual code. Well it's kind of funny since the get request value was a string. This error only appear after the submission is done and redirected back to the same page where the email should then become an empty string.

Comment: Well its redirecting back to a Controller called Contact (not the same as your contact method, where ever that is...) and method index which you haven't shown. In what controller does your contact method live?

Comment: I don't have a controller called Contact and when I do the value checking by echo I can get a string value from the get request after the redirection back to the contact function. Well I ended up reverting back to CI3 instead of sticking to CI4. Was using the same method I applied and everything's working great.